# how can I change python variadic arguments in variadic function body?

Tags: python, parameter-passing, variadic-functions

like `c++ variadic function`, I want to achieve same action with python.

```py
def variadic_function(*args):
    '''
    This is a variadic function.
    args might be opencv mat(numpy array) with 1 or 3 channel(s).
    '''
    for arg in args:
        arg = 255 - arg
        ...
    return args
```

when i call it with opencv image as argument

```py
image_1 = cv2.imread(image_path_1)
image_2 = cv2.imread(image_path_2)
image_3, image_4 = variadic_function(image_1, image_2)
```

image_3 and image_4 is equal to image_1 and image_2 but without the math operation in for loop. and I know it should be an inplace operation to reach this.
my question is, how can I make it when the args list has no inplace operation? thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```py
    def variadic_function(*args):    
        arg_list = []
        for arg in args:
            arg = 255 - arg
            arg_list.append(arg)
        return arg_list
```

anyway, i make it this way.
or we can force the args to be dict type, things get worse, and code become ugly.